# Why is this inequality true in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been studying Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and there's one proof he gaves that made me confused. Is probably a very basic fact, however, I'm not grasping why this should be true. The Lemma being proved is: "Let $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a closed rectangle and $f: A\to \Bbb R$ bounded. If $o(f,x)<\varepsilon$ for every $x\in A$, then there's a partition $P$ of $A$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon \operatorname{vol}(A)$".

Here, if we denote $M_S(f)$ and $m_S(f)$ the supremum and infimum of $f$ respectively on the set $S$ and if we denote $B(a;r)$ the open ball centered at $a$ with radius $r$, then

$$o(f,x)=\lim_{r\to 0}[M_{B(x;r)}-m_{B(a;r)}].$$

Spivak starts the proof with: "For each $x\in A$ there's a closed rectangle $U_x$, containing $x$ at it's interior, such that $M_{U_x}-m_{U_x}<\varepsilon$."

Now, the existance of these rectangles seems to be a very basic fact, however I'm failing to see the reason for that. Why is this true?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption $o(f,x) < \varepsilon$ says that for all sufficiently small $r > 0$, say $r \leqslant r_0$, you have

$$M_{B(x;r)}(f) - m_{B(x;r)}(f) < \varepsilon.$$

To see that, let $L = o(f,x)$, and consider $\eta = \dfrac{\varepsilon - L}{2}$. By the definition of the limit, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert M_{B(x;r)}(f) - m_{B(x;r)}(f) - L\rvert < \eta$ for all $r < \delta$. But then we have $\lvert M_{B(x;r)}(f) - m_{B(x;r)}(f)\rvert \leqslant L + \lvert M_{B(x;r)}(f) - m_{B(x;r)}(f) - L\rvert < L+\eta = \dfrac{L+\varepsilon}{2} < \varepsilon$ for $r < \delta$.

Then you have $M_S(f) - m_S(f) < \varepsilon$ for *every* set $S \subset B(x;r_0)$. Any ball around $x$ contains a closed rectangle with centre $x$, one only needs to choose the side length(s) small enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel Fischer! The deduction of the rectangle I knew, the basic fact I'm missing is that inequality. The point is that if we denote $L=o(f,x)$, then $L<\varepsilon$. We know that given any $\varepsilon'>0$ there's $\delta$ such that if $r<\delta$ then $|M_{B(x;r)}-m_{B(x;r)}-L|<\varepsilon'$, and this gives $M_{B(x;r)}-m_{B(x;r)}<\varepsilon+\varepsilon'$, now how to show that this is smaller than $\epsilon$? This is the basic fact I'm in doubt about. Thanks again for the aid!

Comment: I've added an explanation. I hope that clarifies it.